# CMake how to find linked absolute path for *.lib files

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, window, .lib

I have a CMake project which is runnable, with part of the code

```
target_link_libraries(exec PRIVATE d3d11.lib dwmapi.lib d3dcompiler.lib)
```

How do I know which *.lib (from where) is used?
Is it possible to print the path?

Thanks

Try to find the path to CMake link library, specifically *.lib files.

Comment: There is [/VERBOSE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/verbose-print-progress-messages?view=msvc-170) linker flag: it will dump all the libs and all the symbols being searched by default, maybe `/VERBOSE:LIB` would be enough for you.

Comment: `d3d11.lib dwmapi.lib d3dcompiler.lib` are all library files from the windows SDK. Since these are `.lib` and not a target or imported target I don't think CMake itself knows the path.